# Dealing with irregular timed data with Oozie coordinator

Tags: hadoop, oozie-coordinator

I have multiple sources of data which needs to be considered in a oozie coordinated workflow. Data sets are irregularly generated, what it means is that the data may not be generated some days. For instance:

```
data_set1:
  ds1-1 - Sept-1-2015 - Data available
  ds1-2 - Sept-2-2015 - No Data
  ds1-3 - Sept-3-2015 - No Data
  ds1-4 - Sept-4-2015 - Data available
  ds1-5 - Sept-5-2015 - Data available
  ds1-6 - Sept-6-2015 - No Data
  ds1-7 - Sept-7-2015 - Data available.

Data_set2
  ds2-1 - Sept-1-2015 - Data available
  ds2-2 - Sept-2-2015 - Data available
  ds2-3 - Sept-3-2015 - Data available
  ds2-4 - Sept-4-2015 - No Data
  ds2-5 - Sept-5-2015 - Data available
  ds2-6 - Sept-6-2015 - Data available.
  ds2-7 - Sept-7-2015 - No Data
```

My oozie coordinator job is scheduled to run daily. However, since the data set may not necessarily available, I must pick up the dataset whichever is available and latest.
For the above given data sets, I expect following datasets to be considered for the each run:

```
  Sept-1-2015 - ds1-1, ds2-1
  Sept-2-2015 - ds1-1, ds2-2   #since no ds1 available for day2.
  Sept-3-2015 - ds1-1, ds2-3   #since no ds1 available for day3.
  Sept-4-2015 - ds1-4, ds2-3   #since no ds2 available for day4.
  Sept-5-2015 - ds1-5, ds2-5
  Sept-6-2015 - ds1-5, ds2-6   #since no ds1 available for day6
  Sept-7-2015 - ds1-7, ds2-6   #since no ds2 available for day7.
```

Is there any way to achieve this with the available Oozie constructs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the latest available data, you should use [coord:latest](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.6.5._coord:latestint_n_EL_Function_for_Synchronous_Datasets) EL Function.
Basically, `coord:latest` means, use the last available data that you can find.
If you want to can use `coord:latest(n)` which means

> ${coord:latest(int n)} represents the nth latest currently available
>   instance of a synchronous dataset.

In your case, use the below example:

```
    <data-in name="input" dataset="logs">
      <instance>${coord:latest(0)}</instance>
    </data-in>
```